# <authentication mode="Windows"/>

Tags: c#

I had this error when I browse new web site that site sub from sub

http://sharp.elarabygroup.com/ha/deault.aspx

**ha is new my web site**

Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

Line 61:             ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
Line 62:         -->
Line 63:     
Line 64:      section enables configuration 
Line 65:             of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says:

**It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.**

It means that you have to configure that directory as an application in IIS.